# Join query with limit results

Tags: mysql

```
ID  Name
1   A
2   B
3   C
4   D
5   E
6   F
7   G
8   H
9   I
10  J
```

And other table is

```
ID  Image   Date
1   aa.jpg  5/17/2016
1   bb.jpg  5/20/2016
1   aa1.jpg 5/15/2016
2   1.jpg   5/17/2016
3   2.jpg   5/17/2016
3   3.jpg   5/20/2016
4   x.jpg   5/17/2016
8   tt.jpg  5/17/2016
9   ww.jpg  5/21/2016
10  21.jpg  5/17/2016
5   67.jpg  5/17/2016
6   3d.jpg  5/17/2016
7   w3.jpg  4/17/2016
7   y78.jpg 5/17/2016
```

I have written below query to get this result.

```
select t1.id,t1.name,t2.image,t2.date 
from emp t1 
join images t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
```

result:

```
ID  Name    Images  Date
2   B       1.jpg   5/17/2016
1   A       bb.jpg  5/20/2016
1   A       aa1.jpg 5/15/2016
1   A       aa.jpg  5/17/2016
.           
.           
.
```

Here is my actual problem:
I have to add limit functionality like limit 0,100. in my limit 0,3
So my expectation is if any id coming with query so all id should be come.

Comment: select t1.id,t1.name,t2.image,t2.date from emp t1 join images t2 ON t1.id = t2.id limit 100;

is this what you want ?

Comment: Its hard to understand what you want without expected output, do you mean you want to limit to 100 ID's? and not 100 records?

Comment: Once I added limit, the Id that comes, should all rows comes with that id.

Comment: ""select t1.id,t1.name,t2.image,t2.date from emp t1 join images t2 ON t1.id = t2.id where t1.id <= 5"" 

This query will return all records or rows with Id less than or equal to 5 
is this what you mean ??

Comment: Thank you Priyanshu:
But I want to keep track count limit from first table.

Comment: In the absence of any ordering criteria, LIMIT and OFFSET are fairly meaningless concepts.

Comment: No issue I am ready to add ordering criteria.

Answer (score 1):

I guess your requirement is to choose a set of `ID` values that yields approximately 100 rows in your result set.

`LIMIT` makes very little sense without `ORDER BY`; you're just choosing an unpredictable subset of the result set. So, I will guess you want to `ORDER BY ID`.

First, you need to figure out which `ID` values are in your set. That's relatively simple.  (I'm using `LIMIT 0,5`).

```
          SELECT DISTINCT id
            FROM (
                   select t1.id
                     from emp t1
                     join images t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
                    order by t1.id
                    limit 0,5
                 ) a
```

Then, use that as a subquery to limit your query. Here's a SqlFiddle demonstrating this (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/44430d/4/0).

```
select t1.id
  from emp t1
  join images t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
 where t1.id IN (
          SELECT DISTINCT id
            FROM (
                   select t1.id
                     from emp t1
                     join images t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
                    order by t1.id
                    limit 0,5
                 ) a
       )
 order by t1.id
```

This query is likely to yield more rows than your `LIMIT`, of course: it augments its result set with extra images as necessary. The SqlFiddle example yields six rows rather than five (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/44430d/4/0)